# Debug WCF Service with InfoPath Client

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, debugging, breakpoints

I want to get a Breakpoint triggered in my WCF Service when i Call the Operation within infoPath.
The following i included in Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
```

because im told here [[MSDN] Limitations on WCF Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx)

Unfortunately [[MSDN] How to: Step into WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157688.aspx) tells me:

> If the WCF service is in the same Visual Studio solution as the
>   client, you can hit breakpoints inside the WCF Service.

Is there a workaround? like attaching the infoPath process to my service or something like that?

Cheers! phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the solution which contains the WCF service code in one instance of Visual Studio. Go to Tools > Attach to process and then attach to the process which is hosting the WCF service.

Now execute the client code in the normal manner (whether that is a Win Forms .NET App, an infopath form or even another WCF service). When the client calls the WCF service, Visual Studio should break on any breakpoints you have set.

Too make sure this works you need to ensure two things:
1. You are attached to the actual process hosting the WCF you wish to debug
2. Debug symbols are available for the version of the built WCF code you wish to debug

Comment: I can't find Tools > "attach to process" maybie because i have VS Express for Web?
and I don't quite know what you mean with "Debug Symbols available" I could Select "Mycrosoft Symbol Servers" but ... why should i?

also my WCF service is hosted inside a ASP.NET Application .. maybie this is the problem.

Comment: Hi Phil,

Try under the debug > attach to process. I'm not familiar with VS Express but the option should still be there.

It's not a problem where the WCF is hosted. If it's hosted inside an ASP.NET application then you just need to attach to the process which is hosting the ASP.NET application (whether that is IIS or IIS express).

Debug symbols are the .pdb files which get generated when you compiled the WCF service. If the visual studio debugger can't find them (which can happen for alot of different reasons), then  it won't be able to set breakpoints.

Comment: thanks for the quick response .. unfortunately "Attach to process" is not possible in VS Express [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6wf8e4z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) .. i will try it in my coworker's VS after the holidays and accept your answer if it works :D